# GLEW segfault with functions of gl 2.0 and +?

Tags: opengl, glew

I'm currently struggling with a segfault I get using GLEW. I've tried a few functions (glUseProgram, glBindVertexArray) and they cause a segfault. What's weird is if I fetch the function pointer myself with wglGetProcAddress(), it works. But I don't plan on doing that for every function.

Anyone seen this problem before?

Answer (score 3):

try adding

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
```

right above your call to glewInit. Although I don't know what it means, it fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to call `glewInit()`, perhaps? Otherwise, did you check whether the function(s) you're using are supported, using `glewIsSupported`? If you can get the function yourself, it should be supported though, presuming you did the initialization correctly.

Comment: I have created my context (glutCreateWindow), glewInit() and I've checked, in the case of the vertex array object, for GL_ARB_vertex_array_object which is true. I'm wondering if there's something wrong with using Freeglut? Or my compilation process is bogus? I'm using mingw-gcc to build the project. I'm kind of a rookie with it tho, I might have skipped some options...?

Answer (score 0):

You might try [GLee](http://elf-stone.com/glee.php) instead of GLEW.  GLee loads faster and initializes automatically.  It had fallen behind OpenGL a couple releases, but I worked with the author and got it up-to-date recently.

Comment: For some reason I'd like to support my current HW (which is up to gl 3.2), I'm looking into the GL versions to see if it's worth it. But I'll definitely look into GLee if this problem persists.

Comment: @gtd: GLee now is current as well, with [OpenGL 4.1 support in SVN](https://glee.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/glee/DATA/output/extensionList.txt)

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Hmm so something is clearly wrong with my compilation process... I still get a segfault on glBindVertexArray() with GLee. Have any insights as you've worked on it? Moving to Eclipse CDT with mingw is fun... :)

Comment: @gtd: Check your pointers/offsets being passed to OpenGL functions.  I'm sure you're aware that binding a buffer object causes pointers in future calls to be interpreted as an offset into the buffer until the buffer is unbound, but you might want to double-check that your code does that properly.  If a pointer gets treated as an offset or an offset as a pointer, a segfault is the most likely outcome.

Comment: @Gtd: Also, are you just including GLee.c into your project (which I think is best), or are you linking it as a library built separately?  Other usual suspects are forgetting to make a context current before initializing extensions.

Comment: @Ben Ahah terrible. I could access the function once properly, but before the second access, that would segfault, it did a glGetFloat on proj matrix, without initializing the pointer... my bad. Still I'm wondering why GLEW didn't work, even for the first call. Maybe I should retire from coding and become a baker. Nonetheless, thanks a lot!